# Shimano brakeset hood model compatibility

Tags: brakes, shimano, compatibility

I am trying to find out if shimano brakeset hood have compatibility with different brakeset.

In my specific case, I have a ST-2200 but can only find arround hood for ST-5800 or ST-6600.

Is their a compatibility of hood for different brakeset model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hoods are different for different models of levers, but the ST-2200 uses the same ones as the ST-3300.

The [part you need](http://bike.shimano.com/media/techdocs/content/cycle/EV/bikecomponents/ST/EV-ST-2200_2203-2558_v1_m56577569830609254.pdf) is Shimano Y-6CU 98040. Ask your LBS to find it for you. Alternatively, you can look for 3rd party manufacturers as well but I doubt they will have something for an entry level part like this. Shimano's documentation indicates that the ST-3400 levers do not use compatible hoods (and the style of the ST-3500 onwards is different).

Comment: Thank you for your fast and precise answer. I don't seem to find this part on the net, not even on shimano's site.
I will ask to my LBS.

Just to know, which documentation did you use to find that the ST -3400 and ST 3500 do not use the same style? Because the reference number of the hoods of this brakeset are different?

Thank you again

Comment: If you search for the exploded view document from Shimano, they tell you if the parts are compatible with another line.

Comment: Hi @Akadalow, and welcome to bicycles.SE!  If you found this answer (or any answer) helpful then you should vote it up.